# use ListObject column name in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have the need to execute some VBA code when a sheet changes. For this I have an If-then-else situation.

In any particular row (I have a variable number of rows (i.e. line items)):

```
if column "Type" = Range("A") then
    column "Amount" needs to be unlocked
    set to the value of Range("B") and locked
else if column "Type" = Range("C") then
    column "Amount" needs to be unlocked
    set to the value of Range("C") and locked
else
    the column "Amount" needs to unlocked.
```

In the worksheet change event, I unlock/lock using `ActiveSheet.Protect` and `.Unprotect` with a password from a range.

I am now trying to figure out how to do this. Specifically, how do I use the column names - like in formula's?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're asking, but to use a column name in VBA like you would on a worksheet, you use it the same as any other Name'd range reference: **range("Table1[Name]")** returns the range object referring to the "Name" column.  But, as suggested by Andre, you perhaps should look more closely at the ListObject for more efficient coding.

Answer (score 0):

=== for Excel 2007+ ===

If you are using Excel 2007+, I recommend using ListObject, ListColumns and ListRows (study the object model).

Philosophy behind my approach:

1. Forms, Data and Reports should always be separated, so...
2. Gather all your data into a Table, in a dedicated sheet. Select your data and Ctrl+(T or L). Make sure every sheet has only 1 table of data.
3. Using Tables, you'll be able to make use of the ListObject, ListColumns and ListRows objects.

Here's the finished code for the entire thing.

```
Public Sub test()
    IntersectColumnRows ActiveSheet, "", "Type", "Amount", Range("A1"), Range("B1"), Range("C1")
End Sub

Public Sub IntersectColumnRows(currentSheet As Worksheet, sheetPassword As String, columnTitle_Type As String, columnTitle_Amount As String, rangeA As Range, rangeB As Range, rangeC As Range)

    'variable declaration
    Dim listO As ListObject
    Set listO = currentSheet.ListObjects(1)

    'Takes care of sheet protection
    Dim isSheetProtected As Boolean
    isSheetProtected = currentSheet.ProtectionMode
    If isSheetProtected Then _
        currentSheet.Unprotect (sheetPassword)

    'store your type column
    Dim columnRangeType As Range
    Set columnRangeType = listO.ListColumns(columnTitle_Type).Range
    'store your 2nd column
    Dim columnRangeAmount As Range
    Set columnRangeAmount = listO.ListColumns(columnTitle_Amount).Range

    'the actual routine you are asking for
    Dim listR As ListRow
    For Each listR In listO.ListRows
        'intersect the TYPE column with the current row
        Dim typeRangeIntersection As Range
        Set typeRangeIntersection = Application.Intersect(listR.Range, columnRangeType)
        'intersect the AMOUNT column with the current row
        Dim amountRangeIntersection As Range
        Set amountRangeIntersection = Application.Intersect(listR.Range, columnRangeAmount)

        'the logic you required
        If typeRangeIntersection.Value = rangeA.Value Then
            amountRangeIntersection.Locked = False
            amountRangeIntersection.Value = rangeB.Value
            amountRangeIntersection.Locked = True
        ElseIf typeRangeIntersection.Value = rangeC.Value Then
            amountRangeIntersection.Locked = False
            amountRangeIntersection.Value = rangeC.Value
            amountRangeIntersection.Locked = True
        Else
            amountRangeIntersection.Locked = False
        End If
     Next

    'Cleans up sheet protection
    If isSheetProtected Then _
        currentSheet.Protect (sheetPassword)
End Sub
```

Here's the "how-I-did-it":

1. Store the ListColumn.Range for all required columns (Type, Amount)
2. For-loop with every ListRow...
3. I intersect the ListRow.Range with the ListColumn.Range
4. Apply your desired logic

Beyond the code, study how...

1. I included the PROTECT/PASSWORD logic in there, so you can remove it if you want to.
2. Each variable has a very explicit name
3. I didn't include any hard-coded value so it remains parametric, if you need to adapt some stuff for different sheets

Comment: Hi Andre,will study this and let you know. And, yep forgot to mention this is for Excel 2010.