# Type mismatch error #13

Tags: excel, for-loop, vba

I have a For loop that iterates through each row, I need to pull the value from the D column for each row to use in the loop.

I was trying to use the following to pull the value by using the value of the counter as the row number.

```
X = Worksheets("Test").Cells(4, Counter).Value
```

I keep encountering a `Type mismatch error #13`

Comment: the D column and row number counter is cells( counter,D)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the two scenarios I can think of when you will get that error

`A` You have defined `X` as a specific data type but are assigning a different type to it. For example. You have defined `X` as `Long` but the cell contains a `String`. Let's say your cell is `A1` and it has `excelSU`. To replicate the error see this example

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim x As Long
    x = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
End Sub
```

Similarly you could have declared `Counter` of a specific type but using as a different. For example

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim counter As Excel.Application

    For counter = 1 To 20
        x = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & counter).Value
    Next
End Sub
```

`B` Let's again take the example of cell `A1`. Your cell has a formula error like `#N/A` or `#DIV/0!` or some other error. To replicate the error use the same code as above and you will get the `Type Mismatch Error`

**EDIT**

> by using the value of the counter as the row number

BTW, `Counter` is not being used as a `Row` but as `Column`. The syntax is `Cells(Row,Column)`

Answer (score 0):

You might be pulling strings into a Integer array, or something similar.

As for your for-loop : 
[I just answered someone's question on a somewhat similar problems.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26819243/use-listobject-column-name-in-vba/26824899#26824899)

I suggest going over the fully-functional code example I gave him.

Namely because:

1. You are using hard-coded values (4rth column). You will eventually run into maintenance problems. A user that adds a column will easily screw up your code.
2. Your code won't speak for itself. If you replace your hard-coded values with properly named variables, they will.

NOTE: This might be more consuming on the processor due to the number of intersections. You can always adapt your strategy if you ever come up with tables that have over 10,000 rows.

Check the link and answer, but meanwhile here's a short-version of how I'd do it with Tables / ListObjects:

```
dim listO as ListObject
set listO = Worksheets("Test").ListObjects(1)

dim listC as ListColumn
set listC = ListO.ListColumns("ColumnTitle")

dim listR as ListRow
dim anArrayX() as Variant
ReDim anArrayX (1 to listO.ListRows.Count)
dim intersectedRange as Range
for i = 1 to listO.ListRows.count
    set rowRange = ListO.ListRows(i).Range
    set intersectedRange = Application.Intersect(rowRange, listC.Range)
    anArrayX(i) = intersectedRange.Value
    Debug.Print anArrayX(i)
next i
```